# Access to enterprise account via webdav

Tags: webdav, box-api

if I have an enterprise box account which I normally access at:

https://mycompany.app.box.com (with SSO authentication)

How can I access the webdav interface for this account?

I have tried variations of the following (times out or the authentication fails).

- https://dav.box.com/dav
- https://dav.mycompany.app.box.com/dav
- davs://mycompany.app.box.com/dav

Answer (score 1):

webDAV uses your normal Box password if you have a regular (non enterprise) account.  If you have SSO setup, then you'll need to setup an "External Password."  To do so, click on the gear icon in the upper right, and select "Account Settings."  Then scroll down towards the bottom, and click on "Create External Password."

Comment: If you have SSO you also need to use the primary email address listed in account settings.